# Bluetooth LE on Android

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to connect to a Bluetooth Peripheral I wrote for Mac OS X from Android. I have the following code below:

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        String intentAction;
        mBluetoothGatt = gatt;
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
            Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery: " + mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, false);
        }
    }

    // New services discovered
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }

    // Result of a characteristic read operation
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    }
};
```

Most of the above documentation was on Google's website:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#read

However, I keep getting status 129 on `onServicesDiscovered` and i'm not able to send any data to my peripheral. Is there something i'm doing incorrectly in the above? It seems i'm following the documentation and i'm not able to do it.

**EDIT**

Seems like in API 21 Google made some changes to the BLE API and they didn't update their documentation (obviously very convenient for us developers). I found the following tutorial helpful:

http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-example/

Basically with API 21+ you have to use `BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner` for scanning for LE devices near by. When the scan is done we have a callback like so:

```
    private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
            Log.i("result", result.toString());
            onScan(result.getDevice(), 0, null);
        }

        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            for (ScanResult sr : results) {
                onScan(sr.getDevice(), 0, null);
            }
        }

        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            Log.e("Scan Failed", "Error Code: " + errorCode);
        }
    };
```

We can get the devices from the `ScanResult` and use that for connection and it works on some devices but not all. I get it to work on my Nexus 7 but not my Samsung Galaxy S6. Android BLE is a MESS.

**EDIT 2**

For now we are just using Bluetooth Classic and not Bluetooth LE. Hopefully Google gets their LE stack figured out properly. I'm not able to get BLE code working on most of the devices in the market.

Even Google's own sample code works on less than half the devices I tested on!

Comment: what do you want preciously? you want to write on a characteristic ??

Comment: Yes, but I have a mac osx app to connect with.

Comment: that's not a problem !! do you have the UUID of the characteristic that you want to write on ??

Comment: Yes I do. It is a problem as it doesn't work on all devices.

Comment: can you please put your log ?? did your device connect to your mac and shows the gatt services ??

Comment: Will post log later. Most devices are unable to get gatt services. I get status 129 every time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89862/discussion-between-fakher-and-kvish).

Answer (score 0):

I'm connecting to ios device (Peripheral )from android device as central, I could able to read and write the characteristic. Let me know, what exactly you are looking for now !!!

[Follow the sample code](https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/tree/master/BluetoothGattPeripheral/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothgattperipheral)

Comment: Which android devices did you test on?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S6, which a has a broadcasting support, device can act as peripheral  !!! 
Need support from the hardware level ....

Comment: Do u have any sample code of what you did? I need the android device connecting to a Mac OS device.

Comment: The above code is for the android device as peripheral?